# How to get the active tab In Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to find [active tab in material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs) and save in cookie:

```
var activeTab = $cookieStore.get("active");
$cookieStore.put('active',$scope.selectedIndex);
console.log(active);
```

How can I find active tab in angular material

Here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXxpYG) example

Comment: Have you bind your selectedIndex variable to md-tabs? `<md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex">...</md-tabs>`

Comment: yes. But console.log(active); always is 0

Comment: Could you provide a plunker? It would help, I'm doing this using md-selected without any problems...

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXxpYG  @troig

Comment: I think you meant to put `$cookieStore.put('activeTab', $scope.selectedIndex);` inside your watch? Otherwise it'll never update to anything else.

Comment: Outside of watch it doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `md-on-select="onTabChanges(tabNumber)"` you can "watch" for tab changes.

Example in this codepen: [Angular Material Selected Tab](http://codepen.io/grimaldello/pen/yeRMWN)

Comment: In console only is "Active tab is 1". I have solved the problem by md-on-select="someFunction()" and put cookie in function. Test your codepen example in index 2, after refresh it would be in index 1.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstand your problem. Yep you're right. Using md-on-select to "watch" changes on tabs works. I edited [Angular Material Selected Tab](http://codepen.io/grimaldello/pen/yeRMWN?editors=1011) using localStorage instead of cookiestore, but the idea is the same.